# Загрузка файла на сервер в primeface с помощью fileUpload

Tags: java, maven, jsf, primefaces

Есть код странички:

```
<h:form style="margin: 5%">
            <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />
            <p:fileUpload value="#{mainBean.file}" mode="simple" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(xml|docx)$/" skinSimple="true"/>
            <p:commandButton value="Submit" actionListener="#{mainBean.upload}" disabled="false" />
</h:form>
```

Код класса следующий:

```
private UploadedFile file;

public UploadedFile getFile() {
    return file;
}

public void setFile(UploadedFile file) {
    this.file = file;
}

public void upload() {
    if(file != null) {
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Succesful", file.getFileName() + " is uploaded.");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
    }
}
```

Как всё работает на данном этапе: пользователь кликает на кнопочку "+ Choose", открывается диалоговое окно, пользователь выбирает файл, нажимает "Ок". На странице отображается имя файла. Дальше нужно по нажатии на кнопку "Submit" загрузить файл на сервер. Как это реализовать, подскажите, пожалуйста?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы "потеряли" два важных свойства из текста [примера на сайте Primefaces](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/upload/basic.xhtml).

1. Отсутствует свойство `enctype="multipart/form-data"` у компонента `h:form`
2. Отсутствует свойство `ajax="false"` у `p:commandButton`

Из-за отсутствия первого, нарушается формат загрузки файла, из-за отсутствия второго - не происходит `submit` всей формы целиком. После добавления свойств загрузка файлов работает.